# github "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, github

When getting the error

`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

What tests can I run to figure out what's going on?  I've created a brand new git repository, and it won't push!

Here are some of the standard diagnostics suggested by other StackOverflow questions:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi keflavich! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I'm set up to use ssh:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:keflavich/turbulence_pdfs.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:keflavich/turbulence_pdfs.git (push)
```

I get warnings about X11 auth:

```
$ git push -vu origin master
Pushing to git@github.com:keflavich/turbulence_pdfs.git
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

but these shouldn't matter.

EDIT: https doesn't work either... maybe this is just a github service outage?

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/keflavich/turbulence_pdfs.git/info/refs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was too hasty, this is the error message I get now (about 5 minutes after posting):

`ERROR: Storage server temporarily offline. See http://status.github.com for GitHub system status.`

status.github.com reports:

`21:36 UTC  We are investigating issues with a single fileserver cluster. A small number of repositories may be unavailable while we investigate.`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on bitbucket and i solved the problem setting a more large http post buffer with following:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```